# Display image from json database in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

i need you to help me with displaying images.

The line in render return:
`<img src={post.image}/>`

And line in json file:
image": "C:\Users\Korisnik\appcss\src\images\pasta_napolitana.jpg,

and it doesnt show up, it is only small icon of picture that is not uploaded.
fetch function and json file is working, i can not figure out where is the problem.
thank you

Comment: When you open the that image url normally in your browser, does it display the image?

Comment: yes, this link open up the image

Comment: Did you try inspecting the element and seeing what url shows up in the image element's `src`?

Comment: yes, it shows up the path that is in json database.. it gets the path right, but it doesnt show the image

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, something is wrong with your image link. Try to store this image in your frontend app folder.

Just an example:

`<src={"src/img/pasta_napolitana.jpg"}/>`

Comment: it works like this:           <img src={require("./images/pasta_napolitana.jpg")}/>
 but its hardcoded, i need it to be universal for my json base